# Relative Chop for Fractions with Trigonometric Terms

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review

I have a fraction, which contains long sums of various terms that might include trigonometric functions in both the numerator and denominator. I want to get rid of the negligible terms. This is my attempt:

```
RelativeChop[expr_, magnitude_] :=  Module[{numerator, denominator, maxAbsNum, maxAbsDen},
    numerator = Level[Numerator[expr] // Expand, 1] /. {Sin[a_] -> 1, Cos[a_] -> 1} // Abs;
    denominator = Level[Denominator[expr] // Expand, 1] /. {Sin[a_] -> 1, Cos[a_] -> 1} // Abs;
    maxAbsNum = Max[numerator];
    maxAbsDen = Max[denominator];
    Chop[Numerator[expr] // Expand // TrigExpand, maxAbsNum/10.^magnitude]/ Chop[Denominator[expr] // Expand // TrigExpand,    maxAbsDen/10.^magnitude]
]
```

I wonder if there is a better (and possibly faster) way to do this.

My ideas regarding my attempt:

- Treat the numerator and denumerator seperately
- Expand the Numerator so chop doesn't miss anything or chops too much
- replace all Sin and Cos terms by their maximum value (i.e. 1)
- take the absolute value, since I'm interested in the highest absolute numbers in terms of significance
- use max to find the highest number
- put everything back together

example:

```
example = (10^10 + 10^7 Sin[x] + 10^4 Cos[x]) / (10^9 + 10^8 Cos[x] + 400 Sin[x]);
expected = RelativeChop[example, 5]
(10^10 + 10^7 Sin[x]) / (10^9 + 10^8 Cos[x]);
```

The terms 10^4 Cos[x] and 400 Sin[x] have been removed, because their significance is smaller than the requested 10^5 w.r.t. the highest occuring number.

Comment: Please give us a simple example of what you want. Right now it is not clear what you really want to do.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with your "attempt" does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: As far as I can tell my approach works, but I have expressions with sums of a couple thousand terms and I wondered if there is a better, faster approach to this. Hence the code-review and performance-tuning tags :)

Comment: Why not substitute a few random values for `x` and see what you get? Working with numerical values is the easiest way I think.

Comment: I don't see what that would achieve? I still need a result dependent on x, and as you cansee, some terms are contributing. I just want to get rid of the negligible ones to speed up future calculations.

Comment: Without more context it is very difficult to give good advice in this question. It depends very much on what the numerator and denominator consits of in more detail. There could be faster approaches, but we can't tell just based on what you presented so far.